# php ftp_connect failing

Tags: php, ftp

I have hit a problem with establishing an ftp connection.

About 1 hour ago I modified and ran a script.

Originally the script ftp connected from my server to a FastHost server, copied some files across and the closed the connection. About an hour ago it was all working fine.

I then modified the script, I told the script to delete a file, then copy another then close the connection. However the script tried to delete a file via ftp that wasn't there which threw an error.

Noticing my scripting error I rolled back my script with svn to a few hours ago when I knew the script was working...

However now my server cannot connect to via ftp a FastHost server.

NB I know the connection details are correct as I can connect with filezila with them

Have I locked my self out? Has anyone had his before?

*Here is where the code is failing:*

```
if($connection)
    {
        ftp_close($connection);
    }
$connection = @ftp_connect($host);

$login = @ftp_login($connection, $uname, $pword);

if(!$connection)
    {
        return "Connection Failure <br/>$host<br/>$uname<br/>$pword<br/>$docroot";
    }
elseif(!$login)
    {
        return "Login Failure <br/>$host<br/>$uname<br/>$pword<br/>$docroot";
    }
else{
        // enabling passive mode
        ftp_pasv( $connection, true );
```

It keeps failing on $connection. I was hoping there might have been a time lock invoked and would have cleared this morning but no joy.

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to connect now?

Comment: Consider using ftp URLs with standard file-system functions. It will make your life a *lot* easier.

Comment: Are you using a passive connection?

Comment: There are no error messages with ftp_conncect except my own.

Comment: KayakJimJim  - I dso use a passiv conection but this is established after an initial connceyion has been made

Comment: "Returns a FTP stream on success or FALSE on error" :http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php What errors other than false would I expect to see here though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if you try to delete a file via ftp on a file that doesn't exist FastHost servers basically add your server to a black list.

As a result of being on this black list you will simply not be able to connect via ftp untill the lock has been removed.

After contacting the fasthost team this morning they confirmed this and removed the lock and now all is functioning again.